dotnet-monitor v5 works ok but v8 can't find processes in AKS Kubernetes
I am having a weird issue with dotnet-monitor.
One of our developers asked me to prepare in our AKS cluster a dotnet-monitor pod to assess memory counsumption issues with our application. I went with the first hit in Google, which was https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-dotnet-monitor/ and it worked beautifully.
So I tried the newest option image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/monitor. Our application is already .NET 8+.
The configuration for the whole pod is fsGroup and runAsUser 999. The connection mode is Listen, DefaultSharedPath is set to /diag on the monitor, and the only change to the application configuration is setting DiagnosticPorts to /diag/dotnet-monitor.sock. Basically, the out-of-box config suggested in the git (https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-monitor/blob/main/documentation/kubernetes.md following example 8+), except setting fsGroup and runAsUser (if I don't, the application never starts - stuck waiting for connection)
If I go for /processes, I get all the usual information about our process (matching what I get from 5.0.0 preview). if I go to /info, I get the configuration information just fine.
However, if I try to do a /gcdump, for example, I get that it was "Unable to discover a target process". If I do a /gcdump/14 (our pid), it gives me 404.
Any tips?
Thanks, as always.

Might be a bit late, but I had a similar issue with running the docker compose setup mentioned here: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-monitor/blob/main/documentation/docker-compose.md
Running the example 1:1 on my local machine works fine. But using my own dotnet application, this setup caused for me a very similar issue: /processes showing a process:
[
    {
        "pid": 7,
        "uid": "3ae9c821-830a-4c8c-a684-3423dc7eae44",
        "name": "dotnet",
        "isDefault": false
    }
]

But isDefault is false, so the endpoints /logs etc. all provided no data.
It's mentioned nowhere in the documentation, but as I did some digging into the docker images of the monitor (https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/src/monitor-base/8.0/ubuntu-chiseled/amd64/Dockerfile), I noticed there are ENV variables explicitly only allowing processes with ID 1 (but in my application it was 7).
So I went on and changed the ENV variables to:
    DefaultProcess__Filters__0__Key=ProcessId \
    DefaultProcess__Filters__0__Value=7 \

After this change, everything worked as expected.
Not sure though whether the process ID is something to rely on... Would be happy about a more robust solution here.
